# How to monitor network state in activity until onDestroy using a background thread in Android?

Tags: android

Hai i am new bie to Android. i need to check the network connection throughout the application and inform to user about the network status when the state changed.please tell me how to do with some sample code.thanks in advance

Comment: try this one [Checking for Internet availability in Android.](http://rajareddypolamreddy.blogspot.in/2012/04/checking-for-internet-availability-in.html)

Comment: i used some static code like every time i need to check  public  boolean isMobileNetworkAvailable(Context con){  
    if(null == connMgr){  
     connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  
    }  
    NetworkInfo wifiInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);  
    NetworkInfo mobileInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);  
    if(wifiInfo.isAvailable()){  
        return true;  
    }else if(mobileInfo.isAvailable()){  
        return true;  
    }else{  
        return false;  
    }  
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `runOnUiThread` and `ConnectivityManager`  for checking Network Status after a fixed time and show message to user as:

```
private boolean mNetworkRunning=false;
private  ConnectivityManager connMgr; 
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView (R.layout.main);
 mClockRunning=true;
 NetworkStatusThread();
 }
   @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // Stop Thread Here.
        mNetworkRunning=false;
    }  
 public void NetworkStatusThread(){
     Thread th=new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
     try
      {
       while(mNetworkRunning)
       {
         Thread.sleep(1000L);// set time here for refresh time in show update to user
        NetworkActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
         @Override
         public void run() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if(mNetworkRunning)
           {
             boolean statu=isMobileNetworkAvailable();
             if(statu==true)
            Toast.makeText(YourCurrentActivity.this, "Network Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             else
             Toast.makeText(YourCurrentActivity.this, "Network Not Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           } 
          };
    }
    }catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
   }
 };
 th.start();
}

public  boolean isMobileNetworkAvailable(Context con){  
    if(null == connMgr){  
     connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)con.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  
    }  
    NetworkInfo wifiInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);  
    NetworkInfo mobileInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);  
    if(wifiInfo.isAvailable()){  
        return true;  
    }else if(mobileInfo.isAvailable()){  
        return true;  
    }else{  
        return false;  
    }  
  }
```

and second option without using Thread then you can register an receiver for `CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` Manifest.xml as:

```
< !-- Needed to check when the network connection changes -->   
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>   
< receiver android:name="you_package_name.ConnectionChangeReceiver"   
  android:label="NetworkConnection">   
< intent-filter>   
      < action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>   
< /intent-filter>   
< /receiver>
```

in code:

```
public class ConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {  

    private static final String TAG =ConnectionChangeReceiver.class.getSimpleName();  

    @Override   
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {   
    boolean success = false;   
    ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);    
    State state = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState();   
    //WIFI
    if (State.CONNECTED == state) {  
    success = true;   
    }   
    //GPRS
    state = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState();  
    if (State.CONNECTED != state) {   
    success = true;   
    }   
    if (!success) {   
    Toast.makeText(context, "SHOW STATUS HERE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
    }    
    }
```

Comment: thank you imran.its helped me alot.is there any solution to notify status when the status changed with out using any thread

Comment: @srinu : yes see my edit answer using broadcastreceiver

Comment: @srinu : i known only these two way i told u.these maybe helpful or solve your issue

Comment: ok imran how to use this ConnectionChangeReceiver in my activity

Comment: how to show toast in each activity using the above code when the network state changed?